# How to change marker fillstyle in seaborn lmplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Is it possible to change the fillstyle of a scatterplot marker in a seaborn lmplot?

I tried: `

```
sns.lmplot(x=x, 
           y=y, 
           hue=hue, 
           hue_order = hue_order,
           markers=markers,
           scatter_kws = {'fillstyle':'none'})
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property fillstyle
```

Is fillstyle really not supported for an lmplot `scatter_kws` argument, or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: markers are simply bitmaps; they don't get drawn as polygons, usually

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you elaborate on that? My understanding was that markers were vector drawn just like any other plot element. Is that not the case? And if they are bitmaps, why does that preclude them from being filled here? If I were just doing `mpl.scatter()` I could use `fillstyle='none'`, yes?

Comment: no, you can't. the markers are just copied pixel-wise from a mask.

Comment: *If I were just doing mpl.scatter() I could use fillstyle='none', yes?* I don't think you could. Test it out.

Comment: also, what you probably want is `{'markerfacecolor': 'none'}`

Comment: @PaulH Thanks! You helped lead me in the right direction. `'markerfacecolor'` isn't a valid keyword for `plt.scatter`, but `'facecolors'` is! So I can do what I wanted to do with `'facecolors'`. I wish there was more consistency between keyword names in matplotlib...

Comment: Ahh. That's why I just always use `plot` instead of `scatter`

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `'fillstyle':'none'` as a `scatter_kw` argument, but you can accomplish what you're trying to do with `'facecolors'`.

```
sns.lmplot(x=x, 
           y=y, 
           hue=hue, 
           hue_order = hue_order,
           markers=markers,
           scatter_kws = {'facecolors':'none'})
```

See the [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) docs for more info.